# Why do I get "Unorderable types: int() < str()" or "'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'" when comparing input to a number?

Tags: python, calculator

I have this code:

```
def main():
    print("Let me Retire Financial Calculator")
    deposit = input("Please input annual deposit in dollars: $")
    rate = input ("Please input annual rate in percentage: %")
    time = input("How many years until retirement?")
    x = 0
    value = 0
    while (x < time):
        x = x + 1
        value = (value * rate) + deposit
        print("The value of your account after" +str(time) + "years will be $" + str(value))
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/Let Me Retire.py", line 8, in <module>
    while (x < time):
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The issue here is that `input()` returns a string in Python 3.x, so when you do your comparison, you are comparing a string and an integer, which isn't well defined (what if the string is a word, how does one compare a string and a number?) - in this case Python doesn't guess, it throws an error.

To fix this, simply call [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#int) to convert your string to an integer:

```
int(input(...))
```

As a note, if you want to deal with decimal numbers, you will want to use one of [`float()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#float) or [`decimal.Decimal()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects) (depending on your accuracy and speed needs).

Note that the more pythonic way of looping over a series of numbers (as opposed to a `while` loop and counting) is to use `range()`. For example:

```
def main():
    print("Let me Retire Financial Calculator")
    deposit = float(input("Please input annual deposit in dollars: $"))
    rate = int(input ("Please input annual rate in percentage: %")) / 100
    time = int(input("How many years until retirement?"))
    value = 0
    for x in range(1, time+1):
        value = (value * rate) + deposit
        print("The value of your account after" + str(x) + "years will be $" + str(value))
```

Comment: okay I figured it all out. Thank you so very much for your time and effort. I really do appreciate it. Thank you so much kind sir. There's one last issue to resolve which is that the annual rate decreases with time. For example if I input 500 dollars over 10 years at 50% rate it gives me 550 dollars after one year, 555.0, 555.55, 555.5555, etc...As in it doesn't actually do 50 percent yearly.

Comment: @user2074050 That's just a maths error. You are adding to the deposit, not the current value. You want `value *= (1 + rate)` (multiply last year's value by the rate plus one).

Answer (score 1):

Just a side note, in Python 2.0 you could compare anything to anything (int to string). As this wasn't explicit, it was changed in 3.0, which is a good thing as you are not running into the trouble of comparing senseless values with each other or when you forget to convert a type.