# Turning a string to an integer - TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having the error come up as the >not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'. This is at the part where it says 'if guess[1] in secretNum > 1'. I realise that this is comparing a string to an integer but i don't know how to change that. Any Help?

```
clue0 = []
clue1 = []
clue2 = []
clue3 = []

if guess[0] in secretNum:  
    clue0 = ['Pico']
if guess[0] == secretNum[0]:
    clue0 = ['Fermi']

if guess[1] in secretNum or guess[1] == guess[0]:
    if guess[1] == guess[0]:
        if guess[1] in secretNum > 1:
            clue1 == ['Pico']
        else:
            clue1 == []
    else:
        clue1 = ['Pico']
if guess[1] == secretNum[1]:
    clue1 == ['Fermi']

if guess[2] in secretNum or guess[2] == guess[0] or guess[2] == guess[1]:
    if guess[2] == guess[1] or guess[2] == guess[0]:
        if guess[2] in secretNum > 2:
            clue2 == ['Pico']
        else:
            clue2 == []
    else:
        clue2 = ['Pico']
if guess[2] == secretNum[2]:
    clue2 == ['Fermi']

if guess[3] in secretNum or guess[3] == guess[0] or guess[3] == guess[1] or guess[3] == guess[2]:
    if guess[3] == guess[1] or guess[3] == guess[0] or guess[3] == guess[2]:
        if guess[3] in secretNum > 3:
            clue3 == ['Pico']
        else:
            clue3 == []
    else:
        clue3 = ['Pico']
if guess[3] == secretNum[3]:
    clue3 == ['Fermi']

clue = clue0 + clue1 + clue2 + clue3

if len(clue) == 0:
    return 'Bagels'

clue.sort()
return ' '.join(clue)
```

Comment: Use `int(your_string)`. (See ["Unorderable types: int() < str()"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886881/unorderable-types-int-str))

Comment: to see if secretNum has more then one of the same numbers

Comment: guess[1] is a string of a number, inputted by the player, and the secretNum is a list of four strings, all numbers.

Comment: To count the number of occurences, use `mystring.count(str(my_int))`

Comment: Here secretNum is list and your guess values are confusing.Are all guess values are integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`guess[1] in secretNum > 1` equals to `guess[1] in secretNum and secretNum > 1`, `secretNum` seems to be string so the comparison after `and` is invalid (`str > int`)

if you want to count how many times `guess[1]` is in `secretNumber` you should use `secretNumber.count(guess[1])`

Comment: Do I then do secretNumber.count(guess[1])=count or something like that?