# Is there a reason I'm getting this Python type mismatch?

Tags: python

When I run this, I get the following type mismatch error, and I have no clue why var is being considered as a string rather than an int. Is there anything I'm missing here?

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    test.assert_equals(productFib(4895), [55, 89, True])
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 7, in productFib
    while var <= prod:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() <= int()`
```

```
def productFib(prod):
    # create Fibonacci array
    var = 0
    elem = 0
    boo = False
    while var <= prod:
        var = fib(elem)*fib(elem+1)
        if var == prod:
            boo = True
        elem += 1
    return [fib(elem), fib(elem+1), boo]

# function to return what the nth fibonacci number is    
def fib(n):
    if n < 0: 
        return "Incorrect input"
    elif n == 1:
        return 0
    elif n == 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
```

Comment: You handle `n < 0` and `n == 1` but what about `n == 0`?

Comment: What are you trying to do with ```boo```?

Comment: @JoshZwiebel I was able to get rid of boo by just putting True or False in the return statement, thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Hopefully this post can help you understand your error better. https://stackoverflow.com/q/14886881/7981821

Answer (score 1):

Because you are returning a string `return "Incorrect input"` Instead of returning for the case `n < 0`, raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning "incorrect input" as a string. Your code will keep moving recursively downwards and will eventually try and add fib(-1)+fib(0) which will lead to trying to add a string to an integer.